# putting file content from DOM including PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I have an issue with a php project I'm currently doing. It starts with a file, it is a normal `php` files that contain `html` and `php` code. Those files I read through and do stuff with, unrelated to my problem. I then save that all into a final `string` with everything in it I changed and had in it. Now there is a problem occuring, I have an array in that file *( Shown in my code below )* with the tag `=>` which it is unable to deal through the string parsing or such. I don't know how to fix this.

*The `php` file*

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $array = array(
            "example" => "value"
        );
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <i> the html works fine, it just has trouble with the php part </i>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php where it goes wrong:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("example.html", $dom->saveHTML());
?>
```

Very simple, I parse this trough some code, then get this in a string. I then put that into a file, it freaks out because of the `=>`. I have tried multiple things, the most conclusive thing I could find was that it sees it like closing something. I have `echo'd` out and `var_dumped` which then did most of it in a `html` comment, but then stopped at the `=>` I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

**Forgot:** The error I get is: `syntax error, unexpected '<'` I get this error in the file I put the whole string of the `php` file in.

I hope someone can help me, in advanced thanks a lot.

Comment: Fwiw, PHP's own DOM implementation is very buggy as for parsing HTML and is in fact almost unusable (e.g. it hangs when HTML code has unknown opening tag without corresponding closing one). Consider using a third-party pure-script implementation like [html5lib-php](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-php).

Comment: @MaratTanalin "buggy" is the rigth description, indeed. Thanks, I'll check that out.